# TextInputLayout with subscript label hint?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have a string in my resource file that has a `<sub>` tag and I want that string to be the hint of my `TextInputLayout`.

Let the string be:

```
<string name="fck">f<sub><small>ck</small></sub> [MPa]</string>
```

And the xml be:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/til"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textDialog"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/fck"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The label comes without the subscript in my `TextInputLayout`. Is it possible to achieve this or is it a library bug and we will need to wait for Google to fix?

Comment: Hello Ivan, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding the code you already have for your Layout to your question -- then you're more likely to get a response from people telling you how to fix it.

Comment: did it...hope it helps...thanks for the tip